# "Permission Denied" when killing process

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, permissions, services

When I try to kill a specific process (**avastUI.exe**), I got "permission denied".

Obviously, the current user is in the Administrator group.

**I'm not looking for a way to kill this process, I just want to know the reason...**

If there is a security, can you explain it ?

For more info, I'm the owner of Avast folder / exe, and I got the correct permissions...

OS: Windows 7

Thank you.

Comment: They do that so malware cannot easily terminate the AV software and infect the PC, not sure how they protect the process though. What has your Research effort shown?

Comment: I found this i 5 seconds using Google "Protect Windows process from termination" http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/create-a-unterminable-process-in-windows

Comment: Thank you, but that does not answer to my problem. 
I wanted to know which method is used to prevent process termination (in the particular case of avastUI.exe). 

Someone wrote something about this (I think it's the method used by AV vendor to prevent termination, but i'm not sure...) : 

"It appears that there is a per process security setting that can be applied to remove the right to kill. However an administrator could still take ownership of the process and then adjust the permissions back to allow killing it. The particular windows APIs are CreateProcessWithTokenW and SetSecurityInfo."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the processes showing in Task Manager are actually services that you can see in the Services node of the Computer Management console.  Services can have an ACL attached to them the same way a file/folder can.  If the service is running as the LocalSystem account and has an ACL that prevents you from shutting it down (highly likely with an AV program), that would explain why you are getting a permission denied error when trying to kill it.

Setting permissions on services is a pain.  There are no options within the GUI to modify them.  The only way it can be done is via the command line with the `sc` command.

Unfortunately, the `sc` command, is ugly.  For example, I issued this command for the BITS service on my own machine:

```
sc sdshow bits
```

...and got the following output:

```
D:(A;CI;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)
S:(AU;SAFA;WDWO;;;BA)
```

That's Microsoft's Security Descriptor Definition Language (SDDL) for you.

Each Access Control Entry (ACE) in the list is contained within the parentheses `()` and is called the [ACE String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'm going to stop right there because following that link and trying to understand an SDDL string will make your head spin.

Under the hood, however, all permissions (even those on files) are represented by SDDL strings.  It's just that services do not give you a GUI front-end to work with them (nor even a *sane* command-line utility like `cacls`).

Comment: Thank you very much for that comprehensive and detailed answer.